# Neue Schreibweise von Komposita

Tags: spelling, compound

In letzter Zeit sehe ich immer häufiger, dass zusammengesetzte Wörter getrennt geschrieben werden

> Studenten Typen, die jeder kennt.

Anfangs dachte ich, dass sei ein Tippfehler, Schreibfehler oder was weiß ich, doch dieses Phänomen tritt immer wieder auf. Ist dies in Wahrheit ein Fehler oder eine alternative Schreibweise, die sich in der neudeutschen Sprache durchgesetzt hat?

Comment: Weniger ein Tipp- oder Schreibfehler, vielmehr ein Zeichen mangelnder Schriftkultur. Wer so etwas schreibt, vertippt sich ja nicht, sondern hat so wenige professionell gesetzte deutsche Texte gelesen, dass ihm der Fehler gar nicht als solcher auffällt.

Comment: Abseits von Seiten die sich mit der deutschen Sprache, Linguistik im allgemeinen oder sonstwie direkt mit Sprache beschäftigen ist das Internet weitesgehend ein fürchterliches Referenzwerk für Sprachen und Rechtschreibung. Vertrau besser auf dein Sprachgefühl und vielleicht auch modernen Publikationen wie z.B. Zeitungen (hier am besten wenn überhaupt auf die Grammatik nicht dem kruden Wort"schatz") oder neuere Bücher. Wirklich große Änderungen wie die von dir beschriebene würden auch in den Medien kontrovers diskutiert. Nicht zuletzt würdes du hier etwas finden http://tinyurl.com/ybut4y6u

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meine Vermutung:

Viele Textverarbeitungsprogramme haben Probleme, zusammengesetzte Wörter in der Rechtschreibprüfung zu analysieren und markieren sie. Schreibt der unsichere Benutzer dann zwei getrennte Wörter, "versteht" sie das Programm, die rote Unterstreichung verschwindet und alles ist "richtig".

Aber nein, die Rechtschreibregeln haben sich bisher nicht geändert, Komposita schreibt man in einem Wort, allenfalls mit Bindestrich, wenn es der Lesbarkeit oder dem Verständnis dient.

Ich habe das von Dir beschriebene Phänomen auch schon beobachtet, meist in Online-Medien, deren Texte ohnehin oft "mit heißer Nadel gestrickt" sind und durchaus auch größere Patzer haben. Für sorgfältiges Lektorat bleibt oft keine Zeit, wenn es darum geht, die neueste Meldung schnell auf den medialen Kanälen zu verbreiten.

Comment: Mit heißer Nadel gestrickt - ja. Allerdings würde ein gut ausgebildeter Redakteur (der zwangsläufig die deutsche Rechtschreibung und Stilistik beherrscht) solche Fehler auch mit glühender Nadel nicht machen. Dort werden offenbar Leute beschäftigt, die für das Verfassen öffentlich vorzeigbarer Texte nicht qualifiziert sind.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich habe nie etwas anderes behauptet ;-). Andererseits kenne ich Ingenieure (Muttersprachler, Jahresgehalt ~100T€), die sich von solchen Word-Verschlimmbesserungsvorschlägen aufs Glatteis führen lassen. <seufz>

Comment: Ich seufze mit.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Redakteure sind auch nicht immer bessere Menschen. Ein Freund von mir hat ein Zeugnis von "Journalist Høgskolen" in Oslo und du findest im Norwegischen genau die gleichen Regeln für Zusammenschreibung wie auf Deutsch.

Comment: Ich gehe davon aus, dass mit dem Ausdruck "neudeutschen Sprache" in der Frage gemeint war, dass diese so zu verstehen ist, ob es sich um einen Trend handelt, der sich in zukünftigen Rechtschreibregeln wiederspiegeln wird, oder nur um eine vorübergehende Erscheinung.

Answer (score 11):

Es müsste *Studententypen* oder *Studenten-Typen* heißen. Oder eben umschrieben werden als *Typen von Studenten*. Auch *Studenten, die jeder kennt* wäre richtig.

Deppenleerzeichen sind nicht korrekt. Es besteht eine gewisse Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die Quelle ursprünglich englisch ist. Das heißt, ein Titel wie "student types everyone knows" wurde fehlerhaft übersetzt. Da das ganze sehr nach einer Klickstrecke klingt, würde ich auch nicht mit sonderlich viel Sorgfalt bei Rechtschreibung/Grammatik rechnen.